# How rude is "fressen"?

Tags: translation

According to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30236/how-rude-is-to-eat-like-a-pig), I'd assume that "**fressen**" is insulting cause it's defined "**to eat like a pig**". Am I right?

> Das im Kalender ruhig ist, sonst aber Menschen plagt und **frisst**.

Does this sentence have negative connotation?

**EDIT**:
The example is from a German riddle, complete form:

> Was ist das, das im Wasser lebt
>
> und noch am Sternenhimmel schwebt?
>
> Das im Kalender ruhig ist
>
> sonst aber Menschen plagt und frisst?
>
> Schwarz kommt es in die Küchen,
>
> rot steht's dann auf den Tischen

And the answer is "der Krebs" (crab, cancer).

Comment: Incidentally, Old English had this distinction as well: _etan_ > _to eat_ vs _fretan_ (of animals).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fressen is not actually defined as "to eat like a pig" - it is the correct term to describe when *animals* are eating:

> Du isst, aber dein Hund frisst.
>
> Du trinkst, aber dein Hund säuft.

The latter is technically correct, though many people say that animals do *trinken*.

As with many things describing animals or what animals do, *fressen* is considered rude when talking about humans. In the meantime, Deve provides some examples where *fressen* is used without insulting - in cases where it's not a human eating.

Your sample sentence seems to relate *frisst* to *something* that is not human, but rather eating humans. In that context, *fressen* may be the right choice. *Essen* may even have humorous connotation when not used with humans. *Fressen* is fine not only if an animal is eating, but also if *something*'s eating.

Comment: Edited for more context. "[...] der Menschen frisst" is referring to humans, Isn't it?

Comment: +1 The other answer misses that *fressen* is the default word for animals (although of course there are special terms like *äsen* and I'm sure a lot more).

Comment: @musiKk: *(ab)weiden*, *grasen*? :) The latter is of course today also used colloquially, in the form *abgrasen*...

Comment: @Gigili: It is referring to humans, but the humans are the _objects_ and not the _subjects_ of that sentence.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: "Menschen" is the subject in "der Menschen frisst","der Krebs" is the object.

Comment: @Gigili: Not true. The "Krebs" ("cancer") is eating "Menschen" (accusative).

Comment: @Gigili: Nope, then it would be "den Menschen fressen".

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt and @OregonGhost: My mistake, I thought Menschen is the subject and fressen refers to Menschen, that's why I asked the question!

Comment: Bart's "Eat my shorts" is "Friss' meine Shorts".

Comment: Also, people "saufen", too, when they drink (lots of) alcohol.

Answer (score 21):

*Fressen* as a synonym of eating is quite rude. You're right with your definition as *to eat like a pig/animal*. You would never use it in a formal context except when talking about animals. It's considered vulgar. Some people might use it with humans, but I wouldn't recommend doing it.

In other contexts it's okay to use *fressen*. Some examples:

> Die Hausarbeit frisst eine Menge Zeit

Housework is consuming a lot of time.

> Der Kopierer hat meinen Brief gefressen.

The copy machine pulled in my letter and destroyed it.

> Der neue Bahnhof wird Unmengen von Geld fressen/verschlingen.

The new station will require a huge amount of money.

All the examples above use *fressen* in the sense of consuming something with the connotation of greed or excess. *Verschlingen* in these examples is a more formal synonym to *fressen*.

The following example, however, is a common idiom:

> Den habe ich gefressen.

I don't like him.

The verb *fressen* is also used in more figurative ways:

> Der Bohrer frisst sich in das Gestein.

The drill eats itself into the rock.

Finally, there's a verb that has been derived from *fressen*: *etw. ausfressen*. It's mostly used with children that have played a trick on someone:

> Was habt ihr jetzt schon wieder ausgefressen?

In my opinion, the usage of *fressen* in your example isn't rude. A person can be eaten up by a disease or a bad feeling. Especially for cancer, this imagery is used from time to time. For example, you can say

> Seine Gier frisst ihn auf.

It means that a person is heavily influenced by a feeling (here: greed) so that their personality changes gradually.

Comment: +1, great examples for *not being rude*, though of course colloquial.

Comment: *"Jemanden/Etwas zum Fressen gern haben"* is another positive example.

Comment: "It means that a person is heavily influenced by a feeling (here:greed)" has no negative connotation, so why you said it's quite rude? Can it be used when someone love a kind of food without being impolite? "er frisst den SchokoladenKuchen in ca. 1 minuten?"

Comment: @Gigili: That's actually no problem: A Milchschnitte is basically [the same](http://www.abgespeist.de/milch_schnitte/index_ger.html) as a Schokoladenkuchen, and you can eat it well under one minute. No, seriously, you'd be impolite saying that, unless you're definitely joking and/or know the person well. There are only certain (mostly colloquial) usages like the ones Deve mentions where it wouldn't be impolite in a serious context.

Comment: @Gigili: I said: "...the usage of *fressen* in your example isn't rude". I only said it'd be rude when using it as a synonym for somone eating.

Comment: I don't know if "fressen" is strictly rude or even negative. For instance, "ich habe mich überfressen" is a completely acceptable thing to say.

Comment: @Raphael I would disagree in most situations. I wouldn't say this when having lunch with my collegues, for example. Not to speak of a business or other formal dinner. I would only use it with close friends.

Comment: @Deve Agreed; is this an issue with the phrase, though? That is, would you say, "Ich habe zu viel gegessen."? My gut feeling would be that you would do neither but rather take extra care *not* too eat to much, or suck it up silently if you do.

Comment: @Raphael Also true, yes. *sich überfressen* is maybe not rude in the sense of insulting but I still think it's a little bit vulgar.

Answer (score 1):

> Menschen essen und trinken. Tiere fressen und saufen.

You use a different verb, depending on who is eating or drinking.

> Herr Meier frisst.

would translate: Mr. Meier is eating like an animal. - Which would be insulting and therefore rude.

Oh the other hand, it would sound strange to say:

> Du willst mit dem Hund Gassi gehen? Warte noch ein paar Minuten! Er ist gerade beim Essen.