# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "essen" und "fressen"?

Tags: meaning, difference, synonym

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *essen* und *fressen*? Was genau bedeutet *fressen* eigentlich?

Ich habe in einem Wörterbuch nachgeschlagen, aber beide Wörter wurden mit *to eat* ins Englische übersetzt. Daher meine Frage, was nun der Unterschied ist?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/how-rude-is-fressen

Comment: @CarstenS Vielen Dank.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Menschen essen, andere Tiere fressen.

Daher wird fressen auch abwertend für ein gieriges, unzivilisiertes Essen von Menschen verwendet, kann aber auch metaphorisch gebraucht werden, wenn ein Automat ein Papier zerreisst, etwa: `der Automat hat meinen Fahrschein gefressen`, oder wenn man geistige Inhalte konsumiert: `Die Schüler haben endlich die binomische Formel gefressen.`

Comment: Ich habe die Diskussion über das Wort *andere* in den [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41174/discussion-on-answer-by-user-unknown-was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-essen-un) ausgelagert, da sie meines Erachtens nicht zu Missverständnissen der Antwort führen kann und das auch keiner der Kommentatoren behauptet hat.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Dein Edit hat die Nebensache so hervorgehoben, dass sie als Hauptsache erscheint. Das habe ich zurückgerollt, denn es ist nicht in meinem Sinne. Das `etwa` halte ich auch nicht für falsch.

Comment: [Pflanzen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleischfressende_Pflanzen) fressen auch, falls sie das können. (+1 für *andere* warum auch immer wurde mein Kommentar gelöscht.)

Comment: Die Auszeichnung `code` sollte nur für solchen verwendet werden. Aber ich will hier jetzt nicht editieren, damit das nicht nach Edit-War aussieht.

Answer (score 3):

Schon im Althochdeutschen (8. Jh.) gab es den Unterschied *eʒʒan* und *freʒʒan*. Im Altenglischen gab es *etan* (engl. heute: to eat) und *fretan* (engl. heute: to fret). In dieser Historie sieht man noch die starke Verwandtschaft beider Sprachen. 
Später hat sich die Bedeutung von *fretan*/*freʒʒan* auseinander entwickelt. Außer der zerstörerischen Abnutzung (to fret/(durch)fressen) bezeichnet es im Deutschen außerdem noch die Nahrungsaufnahme der Tiere (fressen) bzw. unmäßiges oder gieriges Verschlingen. <sup>[(1)](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=fressen)</sup><sup>[(2)](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=essen)</sup><sup>[(3)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=eat)</sup><sup>[(4)](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=to%20fret&searchLoc=-1&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on&pos=0)</sup>

Comment: Das gleiche mit *saufen* <=> *trinken*, das im Englischen auf *sūpan* zurück geht und heute noch als *to sup* in anderer Bedeutung als im Deutschen vorkommt.