# Können Tiere essen?

Tags: word-usage

In welchen Situationen/in welchem Kontext wäre die Verwendung des Wortes "essen" für Tiere wenn nicht berechtigt, dann wenigstens nicht unnatürlich? Der gestiefelte Kater, zum Beispiel - frisst er oder ißt er? Ich konnte [im Originaltext](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/-6248/93) dazu nichts finden. Oder in Animation für Kinder vielleicht?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Der generelle Unterschied zwischen *essen* und *fressen* scheint bekannt, der Vollständigkeit halber sei aber [diese](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30301/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-essen-und-fressen) Frage dazu erwähnt.

Im Allgemeinen beantwortet das aber auch deine Frage. So wie ein Mensch *fressen* kann, sich beim Essen also "tierisch" verhält, so kann z.B. in Fabeln ein Tier auch *essen*. Schreibt man, dass der gestiefelte Kater *isst*, so impliziert man damit ein ausgesprochen menschliches Verhalten, also höchst wahrscheinlich mit Besteck und guten Tischmanieren. Ein Tier kann also durchaus "kultivierter" *fressen*, bevor man von *essen* spricht, als ein Mensch *isst*, bevor man von *fressen* spricht. In beiden Richtungen gilt es als starkes Stilmittel, um die Abweichung von der Norm darzustellen.

Die tatsächliche Verwendung dieses Stilmittels kann natürlich je nach Text abweichen. Ein Beispiel wäre *Der Wolf und die sieben Geißlein*, wo davon gesprochen wird, dass der Wolf die Geißlein *fressen* will, sie aber austrickst, indem er Kreide *isst*. Wären die Geißlein gerade beim Frühstück gewesen, hätte man wohl auch davon gesprochen, dass sie ihr Frühstück *essen*.

Alles in allem ist, mal wieder, der Kontext entscheidend. Zusammenfassend kann man also sagen, dass man *essen* bei Tieren als Stilmittel verwenden kann, um die Tätigkeit von *fressen* abzugrenzen.

Comment: Umgekehrt kann man auch sagen, dass man _fressen_ bei Menschen als Stilmittel verwenden kann, um eine unzivilisierte Nahrungsaufnahme zu verdeutlichen.

Comment: @clemens Ganz genau.